# How does the recyclying of rows in an listView work when working with a view holder?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewholder

I have defined a ViewHolder for my ListView rows like this:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
class ViewHolder 
{
ImageView icon=null;
TextView size=null;
ViewHolder(View row) 
{
   this.icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
   this.size=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.size);
}
}
```

and the `getView()` method of the adapter class looks like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
ViewGroup parent) {
View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
if (holder==null) {
holder=new ViewHolder(row);
row.setTag(holder);
}
if (getModel(position).length()>4) {
holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
}
else {
holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
}
holder.size.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.size_template), items[position].length()));
return(row);
}
```

Now my question are:

1. Under what circumstances will the `getTag()` call on the View return null?
2. What does the `row.setTag(holder)` do and and how does it reinitialize the ViewHolder?
3. How does recyclying of Views work in ListView and how does `getTag()` and `setTag()` help us with that while using an Adapter?

I am a bit confused with the working mechanism and have searched Stack Overflow without finding any results.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason that you're using a ListView with viewholder pattern instead of a RecyclerView?

Comment: @SpaceBison As the ListView is not deprecated it , I was using it in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty good question.So in order to know the behaviour of Tags in an adapter we need to know the actual behavior of process flow of recycle in listView.

`Tag` is a gadget to make our `views` remember something, which could be an object, an integer or anything else, so when our  `ListView` goes to create for the first time at that time `convertView` is `null`, so we  create a new `convertView` and put all of our references of the `row` `objects`  in a `viewHolder`, then save our `viewHolder` into the memory of that `convertView`(`setTag`). Android takes our `convertView` and place it in its pool memory to recycle it and passes it again to us. But its pool memory may not have enough `convertViews` so it again passes a new `convertView` thats `null`. So again the story is repeated till the pool of android is filled up. After that `android` takes a `convertView` from its pool and passes it to us. You will find that its not null so you ask it where are my object references that I gave to you for the first time using `getTag()` so you will get those and do whatever you like.

This is the process flow of list ViewHolder  but if you want to know more about setTag() and getTag(), i will give you an example:

Suppose you are creating bunch of view having similar kind behavor like :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ... );
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ... );
```

and then you will override method onClick() like:

```
private void onClick(View view) {
    doAction(0); // here 0 for button 1 and 1 for button 2. 
}
```

this is because you are getting only one parameter View in `onclick()` method, you can use setTag() to change its behavior using the values '0' and '1' to access the different button :
just add

```
button1.setTag(0);
button2.setTag(1);
```

Now you can use the same OnClickListener for every button by getting the tag attached to the View by using the function getTag():

```
listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        doAction(view.getTag());
    }
};
```

this is because you are putting your views into the pool memory by using `setTag()` method and then getting these views from pool accordingly.

Comment: thank you, very well explained, just one doubt, in the second senario do i have to attach same listener to both the buttons? I see that working only  in this case.

Comment: yes same listener will work for both of the buttons.